# How to set action for a button when using different storyboard for iphone and ipad?

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode, ipad, storyboard

I want to use different storyboards for ipad and iphone. I successfully did it by following this [tutorial](https://irawd.wordpress.com/2014/10/21/xcode-6-separate-storyboard-for-ipad-and-iphone/).

But I want to know how to call the same action for the `Button` in both iPad and iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one `IBAction` and assign it the `button` in your storyboards, Now if you want to differentiate is it call from `iphone` or `ipad` you can add condition for that in your `IBAction`.

```
@IBAction func buttonClick(sender: UIButton) {
    if (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad) {
         // It is from iPad
    }
    else { 
         // It is from iPhone
    }   
}
```

Comment: I want to do the same function for both ipad and iphone. I really want to know where from I connect the button to the view controller. Is it from the ipad storyboard or iphone storyboard? I can't connect from both. Whether I need a separate view controller for second storyboard?

Comment: No you need one ViewController.swift file and set to the both file for viewcontroller and then you able to connect the action with button.

Comment: OK.I got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How can I connect the button from second storyboard to the IBAction?

Comment: If you have set the ViewController with the same class you then you will be able to connect.

Comment: Welcome mate :), Happy to hear :)

Answer (score 1):

Create one IBAction and assign it the button in your storyboards, Now if you want to differentiate is it call from iPhone or iPad you can add the condition for that in your IBAction by setting a tag to the button in the storyboard.

```
@IBAction func buttonClick(sender: UIButton) {
    if (sender.tag == 1) {
         // It is from iPad
    }
    else { 
         // It is from iPhone
    }   
}
```